# adding a style to a grid ImageView item when clicked

Tags: android, onclick, grid, imageview

I have a grid layout which contains ImageViews.

When there is a click on a certain image in the grid, I want to add to this imageView a style dynamically, so after the click was performed, a frame to the photo will be added (to remark this photo was selected!)

I created a tyle for this, and when I add the style to a static imageView, by the line: style="@style/myImageView", like this:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        style="@style/myImageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/multiPlayerButton"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:src="@drawable/just_a_photo" />
```

it works, and the frame is added to the imageView. 
but I don't know how to do this to an ImageView item inside a grid.

It will be lovely if someone can help.

Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try add attribute `android:drawSelectorOnTop` on your `GridView` as `true`

```
<GridView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"/>
```

---

Tips

set clicked-drawable to a "selector":

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/clicked" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />

</selector>
```

then set this selector to the GridView

```
<GridView
    android:listSelector="@drawable/yourSelector"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"/>
```

and your image item should not intercept the click event self,
set a "OnItemClickListener" to the GridView for handle item click event instead

```
GridView grid = (Grid)findViewById(grid);
grid.setOnItemClickListener(yourItemClickListener);
```

Comment: Hey yarom, thanks for the answer! After I added it, what to do next? How to insert the style when an ImageView inside a grid was clicked? Do I need to add a certain line inside the onClick method of the imageView itself? And of so, could you give a short code example? Thanks a lot!!:)